# extjs cache picture with same name when I reload grid & store

Tags: caching, extjs, grid, extjs4, store

I have grid with some pictures, I edit my picture and I save my picture, then I reload the store and refresh the grid but the picture doesn't change, because browser cached the old picture in grid. But when I reload my browser it works.
How can I reload or refresh the grid that my new picture load?
I should mention: I must save picture with same name.
I used this statement but it didn't work:

```
Ext.getCmp('grid').getView().refresh(true);
Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('store').removeAll();
Ext.StoreMgr.lookup('store').reload();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should append a cache buster to the url to skip browser's cache.

```
http://example.com/image1.jpg?cb=1
http://example.com/image1.jpg?cb=2
```

Comment: I think timestamp would be better `?cb=1323605313966`.